# handling wiki links with markdown in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, wiki, markdown

I'm building a simple app with Rails using Markdown for storing content.  My question is how to build internal [[wiki]] style links?  Either by pre-processing before they get to markdown or some markdown derivative?  I release I could probably preprocess using regex, but I'm guessing there are others with ready built solutions.

For example I know Instiki uses both markdown and [[wiki|Wiki]] links and I've looked but couldn't figure out how they're handling it.

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the [redcarpet gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet) you can either use a preprocessor or you can modifiy the generated HTML output.

Have a look at [How to extend Redcarpet to support a media library](http://yet.another.linux-nerd.com/blog/how-to-extend-redcarpet-to-support-a-media-library-part-2). This article shows how to convert image references to custom HTML and also how to replace boilerplate identifiers with the actual content.

I guess both approaches could be adapted for your specific problem:

- The renderer approach directly manipulates the generated HTML code from the markdown code. (This is more elegant as you are not messing with Markdown code)
- The preprocess approach manipulates the code by using regular expressions (as you already mentioned) (This is more flexible, but also a little bit messy)